# Websites messes up when resizing. Need advice

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

take a look at this site.

http://testrc-aandis.rhcloud.com/

It has been built purely with css and html. Don't worry about the random text. I made it that way. :P

Everything looks alright. But go ahead and resize your browser. Everything gets messed up. What am I doing wrong here? One thing I know is that I use relative positioning a lot. I try to position every element individually. But I read somewhere that relative positioning isn't bad practice at all. So why is this happening. Please advice me so that this doesn't happen again.

PS-I've also included bootstrap in the html files because I planned to use them, but haven't used them as of now. Not sure though if that is causing the problem.

Comment: Try setting some `min-width` that will stop pretty much all of it from messing up but you will be limiting your site to some degree.

Comment: you mean min-width to every div on the site?

Comment: I was more talking about main containers and that sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.circle` divs are **200px** wide and have 14px x 11em = **154px** right margin each plus  **210px** left margin in the first `.circle`. That makes **1272px** all together. How can you expect your site to **NOT** mess up? If you want it to work properly on smaller resolutions, make it responsive or simply reduce the margins.

Another thing is the menu `.nav`. It is a mess.
You should do the following things:

1. add `text-align: center` to `ul.nav`
2. remove `margin-left` property from `.hg` div

Comment: I'll go with responsiveness from next time onwards. Seems better.

Comment: Does my answer satisfy your needs? If so, please accept it. Thank you.